# Converting EPSG:28992 to universal (Google Maps) lat/lon

Tags: php, epsg

I'm trying to find a way to convert EPSG:28992 to Google Maps' lat/lon using PHP. Is this possible?

I'm trying to convert XYZ: 137634.397 455715.439 0.0.

I'm using Kadaster, which is a Dutch government product. If you need any more information, please ask!

Comment: You only want a solution in PHP? If yes, please update your question title and add PHP as a tag.

Comment: note that google maps projection is a mercator projection. The most common Lat/long is WGS 84 (EPSG 4326)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done using http://proj4js.org/  you can find your parameters here http://spatialreference.org/  the rest is just code.  I have a similar php script in a web page that converts from State Plane Coordinates into Lat/Long EPSG 4326.  It basically follows this logic, ignore the extraneous stuff, that i think can be applied to your problem.

```
points = new Array();
noaa_points = new Array();
var p;
var thispoint;

Proj4js.defs["'.$zone_id.'"] = "'.$zone_vars.'";

var dest = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:4326");  /* Lat and Lon projection */
var source = new Proj4js.Proj("'.$zone_id.'");

';

##############################

if ($_REQUEST['n'] && $_REQUEST['e']) {

    echo '

 p = new Proj4js.Point('.$_REQUEST['e'].','.$_REQUEST['n'].');
 Proj4js.transform(source,dest,p);
  points.push({num:1,north:"'.$_REQUEST['n'].'",east:"'.$_REQUEST['e'].'",zone:"'.     $zone_name.'",elev:0,desc:"Single Converted      Point",lat:p.y,lng:p.x,noaalat:0,noaalng:0});
```

Answer (score 0):

QGis might also be helpful to convert between several projections.
Once you can see your geometry as layer in Qgis, right click on the layer and select
Export => Save Features As ... and select the wanted format.

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html